# Java Matrix Diagonal Difference bug

Tags: java, matrix

The objective of the code is to find the difference between the sum of 2 opposite diagonals of a matrix. Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N=scn.nextInt();
    int diag1=0;
    int diag2=0;
    int[][] matrix=new int[N][N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=scn.nextInt();
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            if(i==j)
                diag1+=matrix[i][j];
                //System.out.println(diag1);
        }
    }
    int counter1=0, counter2=N-1;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            if(i==counter1 && j==counter2){
                diag2+=matrix[i][j];
                counter1++;
                counter2--;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(diag1); // used this for checking purpose
    System.out.println(diag2); // used this for checking purpose
    System.out.println(Math.abs(diag1-diag2));
```

I am getting the exact output, but still the test case at HackerRank shows the code as fail. Can someone explain why?
[THe code challenge is mentioned here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference)

I got the output after removing all the extra print statements!

Answer (score 1):

You've got some unnecessary print statement here, remove them

```
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=scn.nextInt();
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Hacker rank only needs the difference, a single space or a single new line also is considered to be a different answer.

Also I would suggest you to calculate both the sums in a single loop.

```
for(int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; ++i, j --)
 {
    sum1 += a[i][i];
    sum2 += a[i][j];
  }
System.out.println(Math.abs(sum1 - sum2));
```

Comment: got the output! just had to remove the white space and print stmts!

Comment: Also optimize your code, that's the reason you're coding on hackerrank, you don't need an O(n^2) when you could do it in O(n). Also you have a redundant counter1 which is exactly same as `i`.

Comment: Thank you. The one you posted seem much efficient, will keep that in mind next time onwards

Answer (score 0):

You are printing data other than the solution inside your code. Therefore, the output is *not* the same as theirs.

Remove all `System.out.print()` and `System.out.println()` calls except the one that prints the actual result.

Unrelated note: to access the diagonals of a matrix, there is no need to go through all the rows and columns. The diagonals are at very specific coordinates, so you should just check those coordinates. This will make your code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is run should be of lowest complexity and should print the exact output . The following code if inserted at hackerrank  will give success. Also take note of the test cases that give error they hint the errors in the code.

```
int sum1=0;
int sum2=0;

for(int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; ++i, j --){
   sum1=sum1+a[i][i];
   sum2=sum2+a[i][j];
}

System.out.println(abs1(sum1-sum2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DiagonalMatrix{

    static int diagonalDifference(int[][] a) {
        // Complete this function
        int sum1=0, sum2=0;
        for(int a_i = 0; a_i < a.length; a_i++){
            for(int a_j = 0; a_j < a.length; a_j++){
                if(a_i==a_j)
                {
                   sum1+=a[a_i][a_j];
                }
            }
        }
        for(int b_i = 0, b_j=a.length-1; b_i < a.length && b_j>=0; b_i++, b_j--){
            sum2+=a[b_i][b_j];
        }
        return Math.abs(sum1-sum2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[][] a = new int[n][n];
        for(int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++){
            for(int a_j = 0; a_j < n; a_j++){
                a[a_i][a_j] = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int result = diagonalDifference(a);
        System.out.println(result);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code :

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    l+=a[i][i];
    r+=a[i][n-1-i];
}
result = abs(l-r);
System.out.println(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       
        int n = in.nextInt();

        int diognalleft = 0;
        int diognalright = 0;        
        int [][] array = new int[n][n];

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
             for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                   array[i][j]=in.nextInt();
             }
        } 
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
              for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                  if (i == j)
                  {
                       diognalleft = diognalleft + array[i][j];
                  }
                  if( (i+j) == (n-1) )
                  {
                      diognalright = diognalright + array[i][j];
                  }
              }
         }
        System.out.println(Math.abs(diognalleft - diognalright));
    }
}
```

Comment: A lousily formatted code only answer. Such input will *not* result in gain of reputation. Please: fix formatting, and add some explanations.